# How to get the checkbox column sender's datagrid parent

Tags: wpf, datagrid, sender

Hi I have a datagrid (xaml code below):

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FLEET" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding FLEET, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SELECTED?" Width="1*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Viewbox Margin="-0.2" Height="18.5">
                                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=isSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="FSC_CheckBox_Click"/>

                                    </Viewbox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The click events:

```
 private void FSC_CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     ......
    }
```

Is there a way I can get the the parent datagrid object from the click sender?  I've tried this link
[Get containing row from a CheckBox inside of a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552610/get-containing-row-from-a-checkbox-inside-of-a-datagrid), but it didn't work because of the viewbox and datatemplate(I guess).
Any suggestions is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event handler will get the sender, which you can cast to checkbox.
I reckon the simplest approach is to abuse the Tag property on your checkbox.
That can be any old object you fancy.
You can use a relativesource binding for that.
Something like:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={Relativesource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

Grab it off there, roughly:

```
 private void FSC_CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
       var cb=(CheckBox)sender;
       var parentDataGrid = (DataGrid)cb.Tag;
 }
```

This is air code, I don't have a datagrid with a checkbox and a click handler to try it out with easily so there may be some typo lurking.